# Is it possible to set change set type of behavior with Svn like in Perforce?

Tags: svn, perforce

I used Perforce in the past and I liked it a lot but I have been moving to Svn now mostly because it is open source and I like to use the git svn quite a bit.

My issue is that I want to be able to stage my change set prior to commit like in Perforce so I know what I am working on, I can associate files with the changes prior to the commit etc  like in Perforce. Is it possible to emulate such behavior with Svn?

So basically I would have a change list which is filled with bunch of files, once done I just commit that set.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Subversion has had [changelist support since 1.5](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#changelists).

There is a [section on changelists in the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.changelists).

But the basic gist is:

`svn changelist name foo.c bar.c`

`svn diff --changelist name`

`svn commit --changelist name`